# Read SOAP xml response from ASP.NET Core [MTOM not working]

Tags: c#, xml, soap, asp.net-core, mtom

I'm using an ASP.NET Core service to call a SOAP server. I can't use the web.config as in the linked question, since I don't have it.

I'm able to call it and receive the correct response. My problem now is to find a smart method to read it; I'm going to explain.

My response, for example, is:

```
--MIMEBoundary_59f98a3b863640e46b622e5739083846dab4b1825abc60d0
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 
<0.49f98a3b863640e46b622e5739083846dab4b1825abc60d0@apache.org>


--MIMEBoundary_59f98a3b863640e46b622e5739083846dab4b1825abc60d0--

<ns2:res xmlns:ns2="http:/xxxxx/v1.0/types">
    <ID>1162898</ID>
    <DataOraRicezione>2018-03-13T15:08:30.119+01:00</DataOraRicezione>
</ns2:res>
```

I have this xml in a string and I'd like to parse it in my class. I can do it, but the problem is the MIME boundary. Obviously, that part makes my string a NOT valid xml, so I have to avoid it. I can just parse my string and delete the first part with some string management, but this is a really bad solution.

Since I'm quite a dummy with SOAP, probably there are some ways I don't know.

The code I use to call the SOAP is:

```
var request = CreateWebRequest(url, x509);
byte[] bytes;
bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlContent);
request.ContentType = "application/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    return responseStr;
}
```

I tried this to manage the MTOM

```
XmlDictionaryReader mtomReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
```

but I got the message: **The Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) message encoding is not supported on this platform.**

So, I'm searching for an alternative valid for ASP.NET CORE

Comment: The response sample you have posted is not SOAP.

Comment: And what is it? The documentation I have refers to this as a Soap service....

Comment: I don't want to believe this stuff is not supported...

Comment: Can you add the Soap service as a connected service? Won't that manage all the message handling for you?

Comment: No idea, it could be anything. It looks like valid XML, but its namespace gives me no clue as to whether it represents any particular application protocol.

Comment: The response is an MTOM response from a SOAP call.
The ACTUAL SOAP is "buried" in the content. I too am attempting to do this in .NET core, but, it doesn't look like MTOM support is going to make it in any time soon: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1810.

Comment: Did you find a workaround ? even in 2020 aspnet core does not have support for mtom

Comment: @EchoRo unfortunately found nothing

Comment: https://github.com/lennykean/WcfCoreMtomEncoder i did not get it running.